# Foundation 4 images in table cells not displaying at defined width height

Tags: jquery, image, height, width, zurb-foundation

I am having a bit of an issue with Foundation 4 scaling my images (usually too small) in table cells.

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        blah, blah, blah... a bunch of text... blah, blah, blah.
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="filename.jpg" width="300" height="144">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

In the code above, the text on the left side will usually expand and cause the images on the right side to display very small. The width, height values are ignored in the img tag. The only consistent fix I have found is to set the width of the cell to the same width as the image.

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        blah, blah, blah... a bunch of text... blah, blah, blah.
      </td>
      <td **width="300"**>
        <img src="filename.jpg" **width="300"** height="144">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

I would really prefer a CSS fix rather than finding and fixing each case by the hack above. Can anyone recommend how to force the image to display at the width, height defined in the img tag?

Disclaimer: I do not condone layout with tables, but I have a lot of older html code that was built/designed with tinymce and it has tables in the layout. I'm just trying to make the old layout work with foundation 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what I needed to do AND it was all CSS no jQuery. I will record it in case it is needed one day when we all go back to using tables for layout.

Foundation base styles (in app.css) for responsive images as:

```
img {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this is what was scaling my images down to fit in the cell instead of displaying at the width, height specified. Therefore, I just needed to overwrite this in my div displaying the content. I do that in a div with the id content.

```
#content img { 
 max-width: none; 
}
```

... and bingo! They display fine. Good job me!!